# Verification of a certain computation of VC dimension

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, elementary-proofs, alternative-proof, learning-theory

**Disclaimer:** *I'm not very familiar with the concept of VC dimensions and how to manipulate such objects. I'd be grateful if expects on the subject (learning theory, probability), could kindly proof check a small computation I've done below (or provide a simple alternative derivation, using classical arguments). Thanks in advance.*

---

Let $X$ be a measurable space and let $F$ be a collection of measurable functions $f: X \to \mathbb R$ such that the VC-dimension the collection of subsets of $X$ given by $sg(F) := \{S(f) \text{ s.t } f \in F\}$ is $d$, where
$$
S(f) := \{x \in X \text{ s.t }f(x) \le 0\}.
$$
Let $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R$ with $\beta \ge 0$ an define a collection $H$ of subsets of $X \times \{\pm 1\}$ given by
$$
H := \{T(f) \mid f \in F\},\text{ where } T(f) := \{(x,y) \in X \times \{\pm 1\} \text{ s.t } |yf(x)-\alpha| \ge \beta\}.
$$

**NB.:** We also assume that $F$ is closed under affine transformations of the form $f \mapsto \pm f + c$, with $c \in \mathbb R$.

> **Question.** *Is it true that $VCdim(H) \le Cd$, for some absolute constant $C$ (not depending on parameters of the problem) ?*

---

### My attempt

It is clear that $|yf(x)-\alpha| \ge \beta$ iff $yf(x) \le \alpha-\beta$ or $-yf(x) \le -\alpha-\beta$, and so $T(f) = S_{\alpha-\beta}(f) \cup S_{-\alpha-\beta}(-f)$,
where
$$
S_t(f) := \{x \in X \mid yf(x) \le t\}.
$$

We deduce the definition of $H$ that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
H &= \{S_{\alpha-\beta}(f) \cup S_{-\alpha-\beta}(f) \text{ s.t. }f \in F\}\\
&\subseteq \{A \cup B \text{ s.t } A \in S_{\alpha-\beta}(F),\, B \in S_{-\alpha-\beta}(-F)\},
\end{split}
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $S_t(F) := \{S_t(f) \text{ s.t } f \in F\}$, $-F:=\{-f \text{ s.t } f \in F\}$. Invoking Lemma 2.6.17 of van der Vaart and Wellner's *Weak convergence and empirocal processes* book, we deduce from (1) that
$$
\begin{split}
VCdim(H) &\le VCdim(S_{\alpha-\beta}(F))+ VCdim(S_{-\alpha-\beta}(-F))\\
&\le  4\cdot VCdim(sg(F))\\
&\le 4d
\end{split}
$$
where we have used the fact that for any $t \in \mathbb R$, both $S_t(F)$ and $S_t(-F)$ have the same VC dimension at most twice that of $sg(F)$, i.e., at most $2d$. See equation (3) of this [CS Theory post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51371/44644) (note that $S_t(F)$ is called $H$ in that post).

Thus, if my computations above are correct, then the bound in the question hold with $C=4$.

> **Question.** *Does my argument seem correct ?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can certainly remove all of the measurability assumptions, since VC-dim is a combinatorial, not a measure-theoretic quantity.

Comment: Answered here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51371/upper-bound-for-vcdim-of-h-in-terms-of-subgraphf-where-h-sf-f